# DataSource considering File's Absolute Path name as attachment file name

Tags: java, itext, jakarta-mail

Say I generate a **pdf** file **testing.pdf** in location **D:\project\pdf\**.

When I make use of the same file to be attached in the mail to be sent to the recipient mail address using **javax.mail** API in Java, the attached file's name is including  the **Absolute path** as the  name:

```
String file = "D:\project\pdf\testing.pdf";
String to = "<DESTINATION EMAIL ADDRESS>";//destination email address
String from = "<YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS>";//source email address
String password = "<YOUR PASSWORD>"; //Your gmail password
String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //hostname of the machine that has smtp server

Properties props = System.getProperties();
. 
.
.   // Defining Property, Session,Message Objects and the that 
    // is required to set up and create a message to send as necessary 
.
.
FileDataSource fdatasource = new FileDataSource(file);  //path of the file to be attached 
.
.
 Transport.send(message);
```

I know the fact that, since I am providing the **FileDataSouce** with the **absolute path** (location) of the file, the attached File's name is considered the same.

**D:\project\pdf\testing.pdf** is the file after downloading the attachment ones mail received in the recipient side (just to point out the problem, **testing.pdf** is all I want the file name to be)

My actual problem is I don't want the **attached file** to contain **absolute path of the original file** as the file name in the **recipient** side.

Is there any way so that the attached file's name includes only the actual File name (testing.pdf) and not the absolute path (D:\project\pdf\testing.pdf)?

Comment: Why don't you create the file in memory (using `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream`), wouldn't that be more elegant? What are you going to do with all those PDF files on your file system once the mails are sent out? Surely there are better ways to archive those PDFs (assuming that it's your requirement to archive them)?

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, thank u,that's a useful suggestion , and yes the archives are maintained for the associated information.. Let me try with "ByteArrayOutputStream"  .. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Call [javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setFileName](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setFileName-java.lang.String-) after you set the data handler on the body part.  If all you want to do is attach a file you can use one of the [attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-) methods.